# Adding Dropping Column instance into a Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

In general, we will `df.drop('column_name', axis=1)` to **remove** a column in a DataFrame.
I want to add this transformer into a Pipeline

Example:

```
numerical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
                                     ('scaler', StandardScaler(with_mean=False))
                                     ])
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encapsulate your `Pipeline` into a `ColumnTransformer` which allows you to select the data that is processed through the pipeline as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector, make_column_transformer

col_to_exclude = 'A'
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [ 0]*10, 'B' : [ 1]*10, 'C' : [ 2]*10})

numerical_transformer = make_pipeline
    SimpleImputer(strategy='mean'),
    StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
)


transform = ColumnTransformer(
    (numerical_transformer, make_column_selector(pattern=f'^(?!{col_to_exclude})'))
)

transform.fit_transform(df)
```

**NOTE**: I am using here a regex pattern to exclude the column `A`.

Comment: This works notably because the `ColumnTransformer` has the default parameter `remainder='drop'`

Answer (score 20):

You can write a custom Transformer like this :

```
class columnDropperTransformer():
    def __init__(self,columns):
        self.columns=columns

    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        return X.drop(self.columns,axis=1)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
```

And use it in a pipeline :

```
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
"col_1":["a","b","c","d"],
"col_2":["e","f","g","h"],
"col_3":[1,2,3,4],
"col_4":[5,6,7,8]
})

# your pipline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("columnDropper", columnDropperTransformer(['col_2','col_3']))
])

# apply the pipeline to dataframe
pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```

Output :

```
  col_1 col_4
0    a    5
1    b    6
2    c    7
3    d    8
```

Comment: Your class should inherit from `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin` in order to comply with the `sklearn` API.

Comment: @Woodly0 Only `TransformerMixin`: this isn't an estimator.

Answer (score 4):

I think all of the answers here are actually just overcomplicated. This type of procedure is what [FunctionTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html) is for:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FunctionTransformer, make_pipeline
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(lambda df: df.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1)),
)
```

As the name implies, you can define an arbitrary function. Since the operation here is as basic as it gets, I don't think this needs a standalone class.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use the `transformer` special value of `'drop'` in `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer`:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Specify columns to drop
columns_to_drop = ['feature1', 'feature3']

# Create a pipeline with ColumnTransformer to drop columns
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('column_dropper', 'drop', columns_to_drop),
    ]
)

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ('preprocessing', preprocessor),
    ]
)

# Transform the DataFrame using the pipeline
transformed_data = pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```