# How to make scikit-learn's columnTransformer automatically drop extra columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Good Day, I googled this without luck. It seems like it's possible, but I might be reading the API wrong. How can I have scikit-learn automatically drop the extra columns in my pandas dataframe, on my testing data, instead of explicitly having to drop those columns?

---

I am currently running `Python 3.6` in my environment and v `0.24.2` of sklearn.

To show this with an example here's the code:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

import pandas as pd

from random import randint
from random import choice
import random

random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cont_A': [randint(1,10) for _ in range(10)], 
    'cont_B': [randint(-20,20) for _ in range(10)],
    'cat_A': [choice('ABC') for _ in range(10)],
    'cat_B': [choice('XYZ') for _ in range(10)],
})
```

This will create a dataframe with two categorical columns and two continuous columns.

```
t = [
    ('cat', OneHotEncoder(), ['cat_A', 'cat_B']),
    ('nums', MinMaxScaler(), ['cont_A', 'cont_B'])
]

columnTransformer = ColumnTransformer(t, remainder='drop')
X_train = columnTransformer.fit_transform(df)
X_train
```

We can fit-transform our `columnTransformer` on our initial training data.  Now let's say we generate our testing or input data before we want to run our model.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
    'cont_A': [randint(2,9) for _ in range(3)], 
    'cont_B': [randint(-19,19) for _ in range(3)],
    'cat_A': [choice('ABC') for _ in range(3)],
    'cat_B': [choice('XYZ') for _ in range(3)],
    'extra_A': [randint(1,5) for _ in range(3)], 
    'extra_B': [randint(1,5) for _ in range(3)], 
    'extra_C': [randint(1,5) for _ in range(3)], 
})
```

This testing dataframe has 3 extra columns that are not of value to us. I want the `columnTransformer` to automatically drop them and process the remaining (if this is possible) without having to explicitly drop them.

If I run the `columnTransformer` on this data:

```
LST = columnTransformer.transform(df_test)
```

It will cause an error:

> ValueError: X has 7 features, but ColumnTransformer is expecting 4 features as input.

However, if I explicitly drop those columns, it will run.  I thought defining the `remainder='drop'` would have addressed this issue but it does not seem to help:

```
df_test_dropped = df_test.drop(['extra_A', 'extra_B', 'extra_C'], axis=1)
LST = columnTransformer.transform(df_test_dropped)
```

---

How can I (if it's even possible) have `columnTransformer` automatically drop non-relevant columns (instead of having to explicitly drop them)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402691/adding-dropping-column-instance-into-a-pipeline this can help

Comment: Hey Thanks! That still requires explicitly identifying the columns to drop. I am asking if it is possible to drop the extras automatically.

Comment: @ReilyBourne check with sklearn version , as mention below by systemsigma_  your issue can be resolved

Comment: Thanks. That require sklearn v 1.0+. I am running `python 3.6` in this environment so I cannot upgrade past `0.24.2`.

Comment: just curious, why dont you want to select the colums by `df_test[df.columns]`?

Answer (score 1):

`remainder='drop'` tells the transformer to drop columns in the training set that don't fit into any of the `transformers`. It doesn't say to ignore additional columns in a test set, and there is currently no way to accomplish that: all estimators expect to receive inputs in the same format at fitting and transform/prediction.

Answer (score 1):

Automatically dropping `ColumnTransformer` columns that are not in the input data-frame is possible, but you need to create a new transformer class.

**Example application**: I want to encode some categorical columns in the dataframe with a pipeline, and possibly drop some of those columns beforehand as part of a preprocessing grid search scheme. Since the `ColumnTransformer` is part of the pipeline, we can't easily change the list of columns to transform with a grid search scheme.

Example data:

```
ex = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['A','B','A','A'],'bar':['x','z','y','x'],'foobar':[.1,.2,-.5,0]})
```

```
  foo bar  foobar
0   A   x     0.1
1   B   z     0.2
2   A   y    -0.5
3   A   x     0.0
```

We set up a regular `ColumnTransformer` to encode the categorical columns like this:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encode', OneHotEncoder(), ['foo', 'bar'])],
                       remainder='passthrough')
ct.fit_transform(ex)
```

which results in

```
array([[ 1. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.1],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0.2],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. , -0.5],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

i.e. the first two columns have been encoded, and the 'foobar' column passes through the transformer unchanged.

As noted by the OP, the following:

```
ct.fit_transform(ex.drop(['foo'], axis=1))
```

results in a `ValueError`, as the column 'foo' is present in the `ColumnTransformer` specification, but not the data frame that is being transformed.

However, by comparing the list of columns in the transformer (which is a parameter) with the columns of `X` in the `fit` method, we can modify the transformer parameters.

```
class ColumnTransformerExtraCols(ColumnTransformer):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        new_transformers = []
        for tr in self.transformers:
            new_transformers.append((tr[0], tr[1], list(set(tr[2]).intersection(X.columns))))
        self.transformers = new_transformers
        return super().fit(X,y)
    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
        new_transformers = []
        for tr in self.transformers:
            new_transformers.append((tr[0], tr[1], list(set(tr[2]).intersection(X.columns))))
        self.transformers = new_transformers
        return super().fit_transform(X,y)
```

(Actually, we need to do the same in the `fit_transform` method of the new transformer class as well for some reason.)

Now,

```
ctex = ColumnTransformerExtraCols(transformers=[('encode', OneHotEncoder(), ['foo', 'bar'])],
                                remainder='passthrough')
ctex.fit_transform(ex.drop(['foo'], axis=1))
```

works as needed.

Answer (score -2):

The following solution works for `scikit-learn >= 0.24.2`:

```py
columnTransformer = ColumnTransformer(t, remainder='drop')
```

the kwarg `remainder=drop` is already dropping the columns not specified by the list of transformers `t`.

Comment: which version of sklearn you are using , i am also getting same error as @reily boure has mention , mine sklearn version is '0.24.2'

Comment: I am on ``scikit-learn == 1.1.2``

Comment: Thanks for this insight. I am running `python 3.6` in my environment so I am limited to sklearn `0.24.2`. I will clarify this in my question. This kwarg seems to be a sklearn 1.0+ option only.

Comment: This option is present for [``0.24.2``](https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html?highlight=columntransformer#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer)

Comment: It's still the same issue. Same code, per example, generates same error. I created a new notebook, stripped it down to this example, and C&P the code from the notebook into this post.